# I need help in understanding the function of the number "1" and the word 'sum' in the code below

Tags: python

This is the solution to counting upper and lower case letters in a sentence that my friend gave to me without explaining the use of 1 in the statements.

```
x = raw_input('Enter the  word')

print ("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for d in x if d.isupper()))
print ("Small  letters:" , sum(1 for d in x if d.islower()))
```

Could anyone help me explain why 1 is used ? also why is sum used instead of len?
Thanks

Comment: You'll probably also see variations such as `sum(d.isupper() for d in x)` as well which rely on the fact that a Falsey result is 0 and a Truthy result is 1 - hence you get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He's filtering all the capital letters in a string and building a list of 1's for each item in the remaining list. Then he's summing that list. Since the list comprehension is building a generator and not a list, `len` cannot be used.

(Edited. Previous version said `len` could be used equivalently)

Comment: what exactly does it mean by building a list of 1's for each item in the list?

Comment: Suppose x is `AbCDeF`.

During the filter phase, this is converted to the items `A C D F`.

Then the 1 represents each of these for items as...a 1: `1 1 1 1`.

Then the sum adds these up: `4`.

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare `len` can't be used as it requires a length - which generator expressions do not have

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` function takes in a container as its arguments and returns the sum of its elements.

This line, `sum(1 for d in x if d.isupper())`, feeds a generator expression to the `sum` function, consisting of ones, which in effect counts the number of upper case words in the string.

For example if your string was `HeLLo`, it would essentially look like `sum((1,1,1))`, which is equal to 3.

Comment: `len` can't be used here - `object of type 'generator' has no len()`

Comment: the len(d for d in x if d.isupper()) didn't work for me